# I am getting an error while i am trying to add a product to the cart using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, web-frontend

i want to the user to insert the customer information and enter the product details and once he click on add that will create a product in the cart item associated to this customer information.

The main problem: when I try to select a category it doesn't load up any categories

CategoryEntity

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Categories {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long categories_id;

private String categoryName;
```

I have Product,Customer,order entities. I need to find the relationship to get all of these entities gathered on the Order entity which it will hold the customer information and the product information.

in this Html page, I need to create to link this information that will be added to the order entity so when i create another page to get all the orders so i can view all the orders with the information been inserted by the user.

Make A bill HTML page

Customer Entity class

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="customers")
public class Customers {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long customer_id;
    private String customer_fName;
    private String customer_lName;
    private String customer_email;
    private String customer_address;
    private String customer_state;
    private String customer_phone;
    private String customer_zipCode;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Orders.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_order_fk",referencedColumnName = "customer_id")//means will be a fk in orders table
    private List<Orders> orders;

    public Customers()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Customers(String customer_fName, String customer_lName, String customer_email, String customer_phone,String customer_address ,String customer_state,String customer_zipCode) {
        this.customer_zipCode = customer_zipCode;
        this.customer_phone = customer_phone;
        this.customer_state = customer_state;
        this.customer_address = customer_address;
        this.customer_fName = customer_fName;
        this.customer_lName = customer_lName;
        this.customer_email = customer_email;
    }
```

product Entity class

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
@Data
public class Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long product_id;

    private String product_name;

    private BigDecimal product_price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id",nullable = false) //the name of the column in the other class and that name will be a column in the class
    private Categories product_category;

    private String product_quantity;

    private String product_Section;

    private String product_ExpDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "")
    private Customers customer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_order_id")
    private Orders order;

    public Products()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Products(String product_name, BigDecimal product_price,String product_quantity, String product_Section,String product_ExpDate) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
        this.product_price = product_price;
        this.product_quantity = product_quantity;
        this.product_Section = product_Section;
        this.product_ExpDate = product_ExpDate;
    }
```

CartItemsController

```
@Controller
public class CartItemsControllers {


    @Autowired
    private ShoppingCartImpService shoppingCartImpService;

    //Model

    @ModelAttribute("cartItem")
    public CartItem cartItem()
    {
        return new CartItem();
    }

    //Curd


    @GetMapping("/cart/create")
    public String createCartItemForm(Model model)
    {
        //create order object

        CartItem cartItem = new CartItem();

        model.addAttribute("cartItem",cartItem);

        return "makeABill";

    }

    //Save
    @PostMapping("/cart/save")
    public String saveCartItem(@ModelAttribute("cartItem") CartItem cartItem)
    {
        shoppingCartImpService.saveCart(cartItem);

        return "MakeABill";
    }
```

OrdersEntity

```
       @Entity
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data
    
    public class Orders {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long order_id;
    
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "cart_item_id",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<CartItem> cartItem;
    
        private double total_price;

}
```

MakeABill HTML page

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
            <h4 class="mb-3">Customer Information</h4>
            <form class="needs-validation" novalidate="" th:action="@{/cart/save}" method="post" th:object="${cartItem}" id="form">
                <div class="row g-3">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName"  placeholder="" value="" required="" autofocus th:field="*{customer.customer_fName}">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Valid first name is required.
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="" required="" autofocus th:field="*{customer.customer_lName}">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Valid last name is required.
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-12">
                        <br>
                        <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address" required="" autofocus th:field="*{customer.customer_address}">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please enter your shipping address.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <br>
                <hr class="my-4">

                <!--product info-->

                <div class="row g-3">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <h4 class="mb-3">Select A Product</h4>
                        <br>

                        <label th:for="category"> Category : </label>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="category" name="category" autofocus>
                            <option value="">Select Category</option>
                            <option th:each = "product: ${cartItem}"
                                    th:text="${product_category}"
                            >
                            </option>
                        </select>

                        <br>
                        <label th:for="product"> Product Name : </label>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="product" name="product" autofocus>
                            <option value="">Select Product</option>
                            <option th:each = "product: ${cartItem}"
                                    th:text="${product_name}"
                            >
                            </option>
                        </select>

                        <br>
                        <label th:for="product_price"> Product Price : </label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="product_price" name="product_price" disabled >

                        <br>
                        <label th:for="roles"> Product Quantity : </label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="product_Qty" name="product_Qty" autofocus>

                        <br>

                        <button class="w-5 btn btn-primary " type="submit" id="add_submit" >Add </button>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>

                <br>
                <hr class="my-4">

                <!-- TABLE -->

                <table class = "table table-striped table-bordered" id="show">
                    <thead class = "table-white">
                    <tr>
                        <th> Category </th>
                        <th> Product Name </th>
                        <th> Product Price </th>
                        <th> Product Quantity </th>
                        <th> Total </th>
                        <th> Edit </th>
                        <th> Delete </th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                    <tr th:each = "product: ${product}"> <!-- this attribute to list up products  -->

                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td> <center> <a  style="color: green"> Edit </a> </center> </td>

                        <td> <center> <a style="color: red"> Delete </a> </center> </td>

                    </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>




                <h4 class="mb-3"></h4>

                <br>

                <div class="row g-3">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <h5 class="mb-3" id="total_bill"> Total: $</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <button class="w-100 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Generate Bill</button>



        </div>
```

Comment: You should provide the actual error that you get

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: thanks for your time guys, i just updated with the error page

Comment: You are accessing *customer.customer_lname, it is supposed to be *customer.customer_lName

Comment: thnx Popeye, yah it works but now i am facing another problem, in the show categories, products and price, all of these not showing what it contains, like in categories when i try to select a category, it doesn't load or show any category that i created before so i can select from

Answer (score 3):

You have typo in your HTML:

```
th:object="${CartItem}"
```

should be changed to:

```
th:object="${cartItem}"
```

Since your controller has:

```
@ModelAttribute("cartItem")
```

Comment: thnx for noticing something like this but it actually didn't solve the problem, i updated the question. thnx again, and lmk if u see any changes